# how to check if a click event occurred within or outside a specific element

Tags: reactjs, dom, dom-events, flowtype

I'm listening to `click` bubbled events on `window` and I want to check if the click occurred within a a specific element in order to dispatch (or not) an action. The inerestinc part of my component is the following one:

```
const handleClickOutsideSearchArea = (event: Event) => {
    if (!textAreaRef?.current?.contains(event.target)) {
        dispatch({type: <MY-ACTION>});
    }
};

window.addEventListener('click', handleClickOutsideSearchArea);
```

this code works, BUT `event.target`  is an `EventTarget` whether `contains` needs a `Node`, a child of `EventTarget`, then Flow complaints about it.

How could I fix this? Is there a way to get the node from the event?

Comment: `textAreaRef.current` already references the correspondent DOM's node, use it instead of `target` (Also take a look at event delegation in React)

Comment: the problem is that I'm listening on `window`. I'll update the question in order to give it a better context

Comment: event delegation is not in order in this case, because I need to listen to the whole DOM, not the react elements. Imagine a react app within a page with other elements for instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `EventTraget` might contain either an instance of an `Element`, `Document` or `Window` where the latter doesn't have a `contains` method.

You can tackle it by checking that your `EventTarget` isn't `window` and casting your type to `Element`, i.e `(!textAreaRef?.current?.contains(event.target as Element)) { ...`

With some aesthetics added, this could look something like:

```
const { target } = event;
if(target !== window) { // or !!target.contains to check for the presence of the method
  const containsTarget = textAreaRef?.current?.contains(target as Element);
  if(containsTarget) {
   dispatch({type: <MY-ACTION>});
  }
}
```